# sed command - branching to label

Tags: unix, sed, aix

I am not able to get the same output as the example given in the SED tutorial for branching below,
http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-59

Quoting the code here:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed '
:again
    s/([ ^I]*)//
    t again
'
```

The spaces are still in the brackets after this filter.

[UPDATE]
Here is my output:

```
$echo "( ( test ) )" | sed '
> :again
>      s/([ ]*)//
>      t again
> '
( ( test ) )
$
```

Shouldn't that be `((test))`?
How do I get the script to delete the blank spaces in the nested parenthesis as demonstrated by the author?

[/UPDATE]

[UPDATE2]

```
$echo " ( ( ) ) " | sed '
> :again
> s/\([ ]*\)//
> t again
> '
```

Prompt is not back.

[/UPDATE2]

Also how do I enter the "^I" character? I think it is the horizontal tab, but I am not able to key in like other control characters via puTTY(for eg, to get "Enter", I type "Ctrl-V" followed by the "Enter" key, but this isn't working for tab). I tried with spaces only(using regex `[ ]*` instead of `[ ^I]*`), but this also failed to work.

Comment: What is your actual requirement. I am not clear with your question.

Comment: Don't waste your time. sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, but for anything else just us awk. Whatever your posted sed script is intended to do can be done clearer, more simply, and MUCH more extensibly using awk.

Comment: @user1011046: Updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you, you are probably right. But I am just curious to understand how sed's syntax works for branching.

Comment: I believe it involves a pentagram, 3 consonants, 4 punctuation marks and the batman symbol. Good luck!

Comment: @Ed Morton: I agree. sed is pure black magic.

Comment: Looks like you're removing nested parens with spaces between them which in awk is just the obvious loop: `awk '{while ( sub(/\([[:blank:]]*\)/,"") ); print}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bully for you to work thru some tutorials.

Assuming you're using `vi` or `vim` **all you need to do to include a tab char** inside the `[ .. ]` grouping, **is to type the tab key**. ( I use putty all the time, and if pressing tab char doesn't "insert" a tab char into document/command-line, then you have a putty configuration problem ).

The `^I` is from the vi `list` mode. `List` mode is handy to see where are line-feed chars (\n) will show as the reg-exp char `$` (which in reg-ex is an "end-of-line anchor", the other being `^` char (beginning of line)).

So turning on `vi` list mode, with `:li` and you'll see all tab chars expanded as `^I` and all end of lines as `$`

As you say

> How do I get the script to delete the blank spaces in the nested parenthesis as demonstrated

That is slightly ambiguous, as newer seds use plain parens as grouping chars to create replacement group like `\1` for the replacement-side of the s/pat/repl/ substitute cmd.

Given that your example has no numbered-replacement value in the replacement-side, I'll assume that the purpose is the remove a literal `()` pair AND that it should work as indicated. Once you `:set list`, add a tab-char inside the `[ ... ]`, it should work. If not, please edit your question with any error messages that might appear.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the ^I tip. I added the tab char in the char-class,escaped the parenthesis[\( & \)] in the regex and tried again. Now I am not getting the prompt back. It seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: as others have noted, `( test )` can't possibly be matched with `s/([ ]*)//` or anything with a closing paren as part of the pattern. And you wrote below 'why `([ ]*)` is causing infinite loop'. try changing the reg exp to `([ ][ ]*)` or `([[:blank:]][:blank]])`. Recall that regexp * works different than the wild card char '*', Regex * means ZERO or more of the previous regular expression (char, char-class or paren enclosed group). First the reg ex is matching the '(' space*', but then it is match just the '(', becuase space* means zero or more spaces (as defined in sq-bracket).

Comment: YOu'll need to reread the grymoires basics about sed, reg exps have their non-obvious aspects that working thru this sort of problem highlights as an issue and helps you learn to differentiate. Keep testing and good luck.

Answer (score 2):

`( test )`  does not match the regex `([ ]*)`. `([ ]*)` only matches strings that contain nothing but spaces inside parens.  Perhaps you are looking for `([ ]*` to remove leading spaces inside and `[ ]*)` to remove trailing spaces.

Comment: good catch. I tried to remove space from empty parens also but I am not getting the prompt back(infinite loop?).

Comment: If you use `s/([ ]*//`, you should not get a loop, but you will if you do `s/([ ]*/(/`.  You should use `s/([ ][ ]*/(/` or possibly `s/([ ]+/(/` (if your sed supports +)

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain why ([ ]*) is causing infinite loop?

Comment: Because The string `()` matches the regex `([ ]*)`, so if you replace `([ ]*)` with `()`, then you are continually replacing instances of `()` with itself.